# YouTube Element ID of Play Button

Tags: html, vb.net

I have been scouring through the source code of a random YouTube video trying to find the Element ID of the play button. I am making a program in VB.NET where the WebBrowser would navigate to a YouTube video, but I soon found out that the video dosen't start automatically if you are using VB.NET. I am trying to find the element ID so I can invoke a click event to start it. I would be very happy for any hints or tips on this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Youtube uses flash for their video player, so in short, the "play button" does not exist. Check out the youtube api [for more info](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

If you comb through the youtube api, there is a really good chance you will find an autoplay capability.

Good Luck,

-Brian